# Node.js socket.io not responding to iOS socket.io emit requests

Tags: ios, node.js, socket.io

I can't seem to figure this one out. I'm testing the usage of socket.io to connect an iOS client app with a Node.js server. My server code looks like this:

```
var io = SocketIO(8099, { log: true });

io.on('connection', function (socket) {

    socket.on('connect', function (data) {
            console.log('Connected, data: ' + data);
        });

    socket.on('getProjects', function(from, msg) {
        database.allProjects(function getAllProjectsCallback(err, rows) {
            console.log('Got the project list');
            socket.emit('projectList', rows);
        });
    });

});
```

My iOS code starts with:

```
_socket = [[SocketIOClient alloc] initWithSocketURL:@"http://localhost:8099" opts:nil];

    [_socket on:@"connect" callback:^(NSArray* data, SocketAckEmitter* ack) {
        NSLog(@"socket connected");
    }];

    [_socket on:@"projectList" callback:^(NSArray* data, SocketAckEmitter* ack) {
        NSLog(@"Project list received");
        [ack with:@[]];
    }];

    [_socket connect];
```

And in another method I have this code which should send the get projects request:

```
[_socket emit:@"getProjects" withItems:@[]];
```

I can see the iOS "socket connected" message in the log. But not the Node.js "Connected, ..." message. When I trigger the `[_socket emit:@"getProjects" ...]` in iOS, nothing happens on the server. Neither the 'connect' or 'getProjects' events are called.

I've trolled the internet and as far as I can tell, I've done everything as per all the blogs and examples I can find.

What am I missing in this setup? Or have I fundamentally miss-understood something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just realised this was all my bad. I had the timing wrong because I was refactoring from code that worked with a different comms model. My code was managing to execute the emit after the socket had been created but before it was ready to send data.

Everything working now. Thanks.

Comment: But how you get to know, that socket is ready to emit. I am facing the same issue and still stucked!

Comment: Until you get a connect event, the socket is effectively offline. My problem was that I was running 'emit' directly after execute a 'connect' and before the 'connect' had a chance to execute. I needed to shift my 'emit' into the 'on('connect'...)' method so that only after the connection was established did I execute my emit.

Comment: ok, then i think i am having some other issue. Thanks for your help! I am calling emit, only after on('connect ') response.

Answer (score 0):

I have no knowledge about iOS code. But I saw something wrong in your server code.

```
 socket.on('connect', function (data) {
        console.log('Connected, data: ' + data);
 });
```

Above code mean when someone send data to socket name "connect" its will console.log that data.

I think this is what your code should look like.

```
var io = SocketIO(8099, { log: true });

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('New Connection');
    socket.on('getProjects', function(data) {
        database.allProjects(function getAllProjectsCallback(err,  rows) {
            console.log('Got the project list');
            socket.emit('projectList', rows);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: My understanding is that 'connect' is executed when a connection is made and 'disconnect' is called when the user disconnects. Other than those two and some other predefined messages, I can use `socket.on(...)` to define any messages I like. The problem I am seeing is that 'connect' executes on the iOS client, but nothing executes on the server. The iOS client emits the 'getProjects' message and nothing happens on the server. No errors anywhere.